# How to get all string between `data="` and `"`?

Tags: c++, regex, algorithm, winapi, stl

How to get all string between `data="` and `"` in below string? Thank!

```
L"list c s data=\"vi\" c c s data=\"việt nam\" c c s data=\"việt nam ơi\" list"
//vi
//việt nam
//việt nam ơi
```

Comment: Search for `data="` and then search for `"`. Who needs regex for this?

Comment: There is no `data="`. You want the escaped quotation marks I assume.

Comment: usually `/data="([^"]*)"/` is enough

Comment: @chris how about `data="Hi \"John\""`?

Comment: @mfontanini, That's a valid concern. It depends whether the OP needs to deal with it, but you'd have to make sure you know the difference between a beginning and ending quote with the same character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  std::string beg("data=\"");
  std::string en("\"");
  std::string s("list c s data=\"vi\" c c s data=\"việt nam\" c c s data=\"việt nam ơi\" list");

  std::string::iterator itBeg = s.begin();
  std::string::iterator itEnd;

  while(s.end() != (itBeg = std::search(itBeg, s.end(), beg.begin(), beg.end()))) {

      itEnd = std::search(itBeg + beg.size(), s.end(), en.begin(), en.end());
      std::string word;
      std::copy(itBeg + beg.size(), itEnd, word.begin());

      std::cout << "Word:" << word.c_str() << std::endl;
      itBeg = itEnd;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Word:vi

Word:việt nam

Word:việt nam ơi